# Kaggle GPU showing memory error, while working fine on Colab ( same GPU backend )

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, gpu, tf.keras, kaggle

I was working on a notebook which compares the  Keras and Pytorch implementation of same model. The notebook is working fine in Colab, but when commiting to Kaggle, it is throwing

```py
CUDA error: out of memory
CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call,so the stacktrace below might be incorrect.
For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1.`
```

as soon as its hitting the PyTorch model.

Any ideas why it is working on Colab but not on Kaggle, although both have 15GB of VRAM available. Colab is hardly hitting 2.5 GB VRAM, but Kaggle is maxing out the VRAM to 15 GB.